# /usr/bin/id: cannot find name for user ID

Tags: centos, su

When I am trying to `su` to a user I get errors that the names for associate group and user IDs cant be found.

The when I `id` the same user (while logged in with it) it says `no such user`
But when I `id` the same user again while logged in as `root`, it shows associated groups along with their names.

```
[root@hostname01 work]# sudo su someuser
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for group ID 100
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for user ID 44556
[I have no name!@hostname01 work]$ id someuser
id: ‘someuser’: no such user
[I have no name!@hostname01 work]$ exit
exit
[root@hostname01 work]# id someuser
uid=44556(someuser) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),1000(someuser)
[root@hostname01 work]#
```

I guess somewhere there is a permission issue, but I am not sure where and what is making it impossible for a user to id itself.

---

Permissions on /etc/passwd and /etc/group:

```
-rw-r--r--.   1 root     root       1615 Nov 10 02:30 passwd
-rw-r--r--.   1 root     root        743 Nov 10 02:30 group
```

Comment: Permissions on /etc/passwd and /etc/group?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to run `su` with `sudo`.   `su someuser` (or `su - someuser` if you wanted a login shell & environment) would work just as well...as would `sudo -u someuser -i`

Comment: @JamesRisner updated in question.

Comment: You are perhaps hitting special environment restrictions, such as SELinux or containerization. Could you give more description about your system? Version, kernel, anything you know is special (user from LDAP/AD, VM, container, host provider etc.)? Does the same happen if you temporarily relax SELinux (`setenforce Permissive`)?

Comment: Are you using something other than files (/etc/passwd|group|shadow) for the nameservice? Whats in you nsswitch.conf file? Is this a vm / baremetal / container?

Comment: Nullpointer, please show the password entry for your problematic `someuser` (use `getent passwd someuser` or `grep someuser /etc/passwd`). Is there is a `chroot` environment involved?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AD to authenticate, could be that in sshd config you do not have enabled parameter `auto_private_groups = true` and after login OS is not able to create private group what is needed to chmod `/home/user` to correct permissions. Check:

`/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`

```
[domain/YOUR_DOMAIN]
...
# https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/gid-for-ad-users
# virtual private groups
auto_private_groups = true
```

than restart `sssd` and re-login.

Comment: This is only required to activate the automatic creation of user private groups, but the error says it cannot find the name even for the uid. It doesn't explain why `id someuser` works for root, but doesn't work for the user itself.